# Pattern match--lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
my @discard = qw / abc de bond/;
my $filter = join '|', @discard;
$filter = qr/\b(?:$filter)\b/;
my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parse(\*DATA);
for my $line ( $twig->findnodes('//line') ) {
    $line->delete if $line->text =~ $filter;
}
$twig->print;

__DATA__
<data>
    <line> sdfe abc adsfefsdf </line>
    <line> abcsdffedcfsdf sdf </line>
    <line> sdfe </line>
    <line> abc </line>
    <line> sdabc sfefsdf </line>
    <line>
        <id> bond </id>
        <dest> UK </dest>
        adsfefsdf
    </line>
    <line> fhgh kk jj hjsda </line>
    <line> abc </line>
    ..
    ..
    ..
</data>
```

The above program generates the following result:

```
<data><line> abcsdffedcfsdf sdf </line><line> sdfe </line><line> sdabc sfefsdf </line><line> fhgh kk jj hjsda </line>
    ..
    ..
    ..
</data>
```

The follows is the desired output:

```
<data>
<line> sdfe </line>
<line> fhgh kk jj hjsda </line>
    ..
    ..
    ..
</data>
```

Conditions to be accounted for the desired output:

1. Match, Pre-match, Post-match the input values provided in the array and remove the tags from input data in which they are present
   Example: 
        Match ---- abc
        Pre-match ---- sdabc
        Post-match ---- abcsdffedcfsdf
2. Ensure the format of output is in a similar fashion as input data

**Match,Prematch and Postmatch are my terminologies as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to filter out the `line` elements that contain words that start or end with one of the strings in `@discard`? If so, simply replace the search pattern with the following:

```
my $filter = join '|', map quotemeta, @discard;
$filter = "(?:$filter)";
$filter = qr/\b$filter|$filter\b/;
```

Output:

```
<data><line> sdfe </line><line> fhgh kk jj hjsda </line>
    ..
    ..
    ..
</data>
```

Comment: Absolutely ! Thank you.